# How to use data from one class into another?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have the following method in `public abstract A : IVirtualMachineExporter` :

```
public override void Prepare() { ... }
```

I call the `Prepare` from another class `B`:

```
public sealed class B
{
    public new ExportJobRequest Request { get { return (ExportJobRequest)base.Request; } }

     private void ExportTask()
     {
          IVirtualMachineExporter exporter = CreateExporter();
          exporter.Prepare();
     }
}
```

`Request` containing `public bool isAdHoc { get; set; }`. I want to use information from this property inside `Prepare()`. How can I do this? I don't want to change `Prepare()` signature.

Comment: isAdHoc is private, protected, package access?

Comment: I don't see an easy way to do this without changing the signature of `Prepare`.

Comment: `var isAdhoc = objectB.Request.isAdhoc;` from an instantiated object of type B, but if you're calling Prepare from object B and hoping to have access to its properties from within A, the class it is then calling, then you would need to pass them on in the signature. Or set it as a property on class A, before calling Prepare, if you can't change the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this without changing Prepare signature?

Well, *somehow* `Prepare` needs an instance to call `isAdHoc` on, so if you don't want to change the *method* signature, can you change the *class* or *interface*?

something like:

```
      IVirtualMachineExporter exporter = CreateExporter(Request);
      exporter.Prepare();
```

or

```
      IVirtualMachineExporter exporter = CreateExporter();
      exporter.Request = Request;
      exporter.Prepare();
```

Answer (score 0):

In class A, expose a public property IsAdhoc.

Set the IsAdhoc property on class A, prior to calling Prepare from class B.

So...

**Class A**

```
public bool IsAdhoc { get; set; }

// Inside this method, do something based on the IsAdhoc property above.
public override void Prepare() { ... }
```

**Class B**

```
public sealed class B
{
    public new ExportJobRequest Request { get { return (ExportJobRequest)base.Request; } }

     private void ExportTask()
     {
          IVirtualMachineExporter exporter = CreateExporter();
          exporter.IsAdhoc = this.Request.isAdhoc;
          exporter.Prepare();
     }
}
```

Or, you could pass the boolean value to the CreateExporter method, which could set it on the new exporter class via its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `B` depends on an `IVirtualMachineExporter`, and the implementation of `IVirtualMachineExporter` (`A`) depends on a `Request`. 
`B` shouldn't know anything about `A` or what it depends on. It should only care about the `IVirtualMachineExporter` interface and calling `Prepare()`.

You could create it like this:

```
public abstract class A : IVirtualMachineExporter
{
    private readonly ExportJobRequest _request;

    public A(ExportJobRequest request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        //Now Prepare() has access to the Request because
        //it's contained within A, the class that actually needs it.
    }
}
```

Similarly, pass an interface (not a concrete implementation) to the constructor for `B`.

```
public sealed class B
{
    private readonly IVirtualMachineExporter _exporter;

    public B(IVirtualMachineExporter exporter)
    {
        _exporter = exporter;
    }

    private void ExportTask()
    {
       //Can this isAdhoc property be a property of IVirtualMachineExporter,
       //or can the Request be a property? Will every implementation of the
       //interface have a request?

       //exporter.IsAdhoc = this.Request.isAdhoc;
       _exporter.Prepare();
    }
}
```

I don't have the specifics of your design. But if B is going to depend on an interface (`IVirtualMachineExplorer`) then it shouldn't know or care about any of the inner details of any class that implements the interface.